# Availability of PCI express Gen 3 motherboards / systems?

Tags: pci-express

I was wondering if there are any PCI express Gen 3 motherboards / PCs available commercially ?

(I'm aware that the answer of this question will change with time...)

Comment: I know the Intel Ivy Bridge will be prepped for a PCIe 3 integrated controller, but according to the leaked roadmap that isn't supposed happen until 2012. I wouldn't expect to see motherboards getting too far ahead of Intel.

Comment: good point... (why don't you post this as an answer instead of a comment ?)

Comment: lol, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ctrl-v'd as per Andre's request**

I know the Intel Ivy Bridge will be prepped for a PCIe 3 integrated controller, but according to the leaked roadmap that isn't supposed happen until 2012. I wouldn't expect to see motherboards getting too far ahead of Intel